# Is functional promise chaining possible with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

It seems that in JavaScript one can do:

```
function extendPromise(promise) {
    return promise.then(new Promise(() => {}));
}
```

But if I add types, like

```
function extendTypeScriptPromise(promise: Promise<void>) {
    return promise.then(new Promise<void>(() => {}));
}
```

then the TypeScript compiler says:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type '((value: void) => void | PromiseLike<void>) | null | undefined'.
  Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '(value: void) => void | PromiseLike<void>'.
    Type 'Promise<void>' provides no match for the signature '(value: void): void | PromiseLike<void>'.
```

Why isn't a `Promise<void>` considered `PromiseLike` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your JavaScript code is not quite how it should look like. The argument of [`Promise.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) must be a function, not a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

This function can return a new `Promise`, `void` or a value (that is not a `Promise`) that is used to resolve the `Promise` whose `.then()` method is called. Apparently, in your code it must return a new `Promise`.

The correct JavaScript code is:

```
function extendPromise(promise) {
    return promise.then(() => new Promise(() => {}));
}
```

and the corresponding TypeScript code is:

```
function extendTypeScriptPromise(promise: Promise<void>) {
    return promise.then(() => new Promise<void>(() => {}));
}
```